# Which is not true about Ideal gas

Tags: gas-laws

1. Interaction between atom or molecule is neglected
2. The transformation to liquid or solid is observed under appropriate condition
3. The volume of constituent atom or molecule is neglected
4. The compressibility, PV/RT is independent of pressure

Why is 2 wrong? In formula there is P,V,T which means under certain condition?

Why is 3 true? Then what volume of gas do we calculate if it is not from atom or molecules?

Why are 1 and 4 true? Do atoms in gas interact? Why is the compressibility independent of pressure?

Comment: Homework question. You should explain *why* you think 2+4 are correct, but 1+3 not.

Comment: Ahem, you should 1) get a few english lessons, your grammar is *highly* unorthodox ;-) and 2) I was more thinking about you saying "I think 1. is right,because ...., 2. is wrong, because .... , etc. You've now asked five additional questions, not explained your reasoning!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Interaction between atom or molecule is neglected

True. In an ideal gas the gas particles are unaware of each other's existence.

> 2. The transformation to liquid or solid is observed under appropriate condition

False. As mentioned in the answer to (1), the particles don't sense each other. Since there are no attractive interactions there is nothing to prevent the gas particles from flying apart, there is nothing to encourage association with other particles. This can of course be a bad assumption in reality, particularly if the gas is highly compressed, but you should not be applying the ideal gas law under such conditions anyway!

> 3. The volume of constituent atom or molecule is neglected

True. This is a central tenet in the definition of an ideal gas. A correction for a definite particle volume is included in other gas laws, such as van der Waals'.

> 4. The compressibility, PV/RT is independent of pressure

True. This follows directly from the definition, $PV=nRT$

Comment: Elastic collisions are allowed in an ideal gas. Dilute gases approach ideal behaviour long before the mean free path lenght goes towards infinity.

Comment: @Karl I agree with you. However it is not particularly more logical to treat particles mathematically as identical elastically colliding "point particles" than to simply ignore collisions, particularly if the result from the observer's point of view is equivalent. Mean free path is a concept brought up in the kinetic theory of gases, which elaborates on these ideas. I think if you consider these as concepts that are superimposed, it is best to start with the simplest possible. There is a conceptual elegance in ignoring particle interactions altogether that is very helpful later.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_theory_of_gases#History

Comment: @Karl I think there is something oxymoronic in assuming that particles don't interact, don't have a volume (are infinitesimally small) and yet can collide elastically. They are ultimately a set of mutually inconsistent assumptions, and unnecessary as far as basic thermodynamic application of the ideal gas equation of state is concerned. But still, I admit that these are assumptions made when introducing the kinetic theory of gases, and important for understanding the structure of matter, see eg the wikipedia link above.

Comment: I think we're totally on the same side here, just want to mention that collisions in the gas are important from the thermodynamical point of view too: A noncolliding gas would have real trouble to reach thermal equillibrium. Realistic walls would do it, but perfectly hard walls never.

Comment: @Karl yes, it is not necessary to invoke particle collisions if you model the container correctly. It's a personal preference to ignore collisions, and as this problem (perhaps an outlier) demonstrates I am not alone :-). In any case, I believe ignoring collisions makes grasping some topics in thermodynamics easier, obviously not the kinetic theory.

Comment: Perhaps I should add some of these comments to my answer, but it'd probably do more harm than good.

Comment: Well, your point 1 is still wrong. It doesn't matter if your ideal gas has collisions. The "no volume" condition is not very strict, a minimal cross section of the particles immediately gives you a huge amount of hard sphere interactions, but no significant change on the observed $p(V,t)$

Comment: @Karl Points (1) and (3) amount to the same thing. Your gas would not behave ideally across all p or T. Mine would (even under conditions that would condense, say, a noble gas). Remember, the question is not, "when do real gases behave ideally".

Comment: (correction, they don't amount quite to the same thing, but almost. (3) implies HS interactions; (1) implies all interactions).

Comment: Sorry, I give up. Please just remove that wrong, and misleading 1.), before any more undergrad students looking for help read it. It's a corollary from trying to fulfil condition number three, NOT a condition on its own. The correct conditions reads "Particles in an ideal gas must only have hard sphere interactions with themselves or the wall", period.

Comment: @Karl The equation $pV=nRT$ does not stipulate the existence of intermolecular interactions. On the contrary, (1) is more important and general than (3), since it also addresses the absence of *attractive* interactions in the ideal gas model, which (3) does not address. Of course the ideal gas law is an approximation, to be used only when it approximates reality sufficiently under special circumstances. Students should understand that when taught about the difference between the ideal gas model and the behavior of real gases.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_spheres EOD

Comment: @Karl https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas_law#Deviations_from_ideal_behavior_of_real_gases I've noticed that the wikipedia page for ideal gas brings up hard spheres and elastic collisions as properties of ideal gases, but the HS condition is strictly incorrect, and the requirement of elastic interparticle collision is unnecessary. Particles in a HS gas have a definite volume, not so in an ideal gas. If you want to model a gas as a collection of hard spheres, I recommend calling it a HS gas, not an ideal gas. A HS gas may behave ideally at low p, high T.

Comment: The kinetic theory of matter makes the assumption of colliding elastic point particles, and starting from these and additional axioms can be used to derive an equation of state analogous to the ideal gas equation. But the ideal gas equation does not require such axioms to be defined. On the contrary, for generality it is best to ignore intermolecular interactions altogether.